# Reference all jars from a folder

Tags: java

I'm executing a java application in DOS command window using something like

```
java -cp abcclient.jar;junit-4.4.jar;myapp.jar MyMainClass
```

I need to reference many other jars that are found in a specific folder outside my application folder. Is there anyway I could state a folder name in the above command line to let java refer to the necessary jars from that folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With java6, you can use a wildcard in classpath entries, so:

```
java -cp "abcclient.jar;junit-4.4.jar;myapp.jar;..\lib\*" MyMainClass
```

should work

(There's some problems explained here though http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/07/jdk-6-supports-in-classpath-but-be.html)

Comment: It seems like this might also work?: java -cp "\*;../lib/\*\*" MyMainClass

Answer (score 1):

The very simplest way to do it is with the extensions mechanism:

```
java -Djava.ext.dirs=lib MyMainClass
```

For javac, the equivalent is the -extdirs flag:

```
javac -extdirs lib MyMainClass.java
```

It's not ideal - particularly if you *also* want to use the normal extensions - but it can be a useful little shortcut in some cases.